# Code functions properly when stepped through using breaks, but fails when ran without them - Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, indentation

I have a PointPoint presentation, the textrange is automatically generated from external text files. Each line in the text file is a new line in the powerpoint body. Some lines precede with "parent." These lines go through the replace function to remove the "parent." All other lines must be indented.

The lines output to the body fine, and the code works when I slowly step through the code using breakpoints. Note that using a custom pause function to force the code to run slowly does NOT solve the problem. Here is the code that I have to accomplish the above steps:

```
Private Sub Indenter(slideName)

With ActivePresentation.Slides(slideName).Shapes("ContentHolder").TextFrame.TextRange
    For i = 1 To .Lines.count
        If Left(.Lines(i).Text, 6) <> "parent" Then
            .Lines(i).IndentLevel = 2
        Else
            .Lines(i).Text = Replace(Replace(Replace(.Lines(i).Text, "parent", ""), Chr(10), ""), Chr(13), "")
            .Lines(i).IndentLevel = 1
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Here's what the powerpoint looks like before the code is ran:

[image]

Here's what the output looks like when the code above is ran:

[image: Wrong Ouput]

Finally, this is what the output SHOULD look like:

[image: good]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

The pause function I use is as follows:

```
Public Function Pause(NumberOfSeconds As Variant)

    Dim PauseTime As Variant, Start As Variant

    PauseTime = NumberOfSeconds
    Start = Timer
    Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
        DoEvents
    Loop


End Function
```

Comment: what does your custom pause function look like that you tried?

Comment: @Jeremy, thanks for the response. I have included the pause function I am using in the question. Thanks.

Comment: hmm...Are you sure ActivePresentation is pointing to what you want it to? Can you use a more specific reference?

Comment: @Jeremy, although I could use a more specific reference, it should not matter for the code above. It does not seem to work properly even when it's the only PPT file open.

Comment: Your Sub appears to work exactly as it should, but will produce the incorrect output you see when the "Parent" comparison fails. Is your capitalization matching exactly?

Comment: @Chaz, the capitalization is correct. The problem seems to be that the comparison fails if the code is ran to quickly. If I slowly step through the code using breaks, the output is correct. However, if I step through the code too quickly (for example, hold down F5 to advance to the code), the output comes out wrong.

Comment: Try replace `Left(.Lines(i).Text, 6) <> "parent"` with `InStr(1, .Lines(i).Text, "parent", vbTextCompare) = 1` but **reverse the actions** in the IF block.

Comment: @Patrick, this does not seem to be the issue. Although some strings may include 'parent' in my user's output, just never in the beginning. As such, I need to use the Left function.

Comment: The `InStr()` returns the position of the first occurrence, so if it returns 1, it means the text begins with the string you are looking for, regardless of cases. e.g. "pArEnT" is same as "parent" when `vbTextCompare` is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. PowerPoint is awfully finicky when it comes to referencing lines in a TextRange. As such, my `Replace` functions used within the conditionals were altering the line orders causing some lines to be skipped, missing the conditional. As such I've altered the code to the following:

```
Private Sub Indenter(slideName)

With ActivePresentation.Slides(slideName).Shapes("ContentHolder").TextFrame.TextRange
    For i = 1 To .Lines.count
        If Left(.Lines(i).Text, 6) <> "parent" Then
            .Lines(i).IndentLevel = 2
        Else
            .Lines(i).IndentLevel = 1
        End If
    Next i

    For i = .Lines.count To 1 Step -1
        If Left(.Lines(i).Text, 6) = "parent" Then
            .Lines(i).Text = Replace(Replace(Replace(.Lines(i).Text, "parent", ""), Chr(10), ""), Chr(13), "")
        End If
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

The text replaces are done after the indenting is finished. This ensures that no lines are altered, causing some to get skipped. The loop which does the replacing is done in reverse for the same reason. Powerpoint likes to add total lines (though not distinguishable on screen, but when looping through the lines and printing their text content, you can see this phenomenon) when replacing. The loop in reverse will ignore these extra lines. For extra safety, one could loop through twice.